# How do I show a specific web page to a specific user

Tags: html, apache, web, web-testing

Suppose I have made 2 static web pages and hosted them using virtual host. Let the names be `example.com/page1.html` and `example.com/page2.html`.

Now **user A** has his own unique browser with a unique `USER_AGENT` string. I have to make sure that when the **user A** tries to access `example.com` from his browser, he will be shown `example.com/page2.html`.

If anyone else tries to access the URL, they should be shown `example.com/page1`

Please someone help me out with this problem.

**UPDATE 1**

This can be done inculcating the `USER_ACCESS` string.

Comment: Look at the documentation for mod_rewrite

Comment: @Quentin's answer is the simplest, but I'd probably use some server-side language (e.g. PHP) or a framework to do that.

Comment: @Quentin how do i use mod_rewrite in this please can you be more elaborative..

Comment: @TaDev No. I’m not expert enough in mod_rewrite to answer the question without setting up a test server, getting the mod_rewite manual and teaching myself it practically from scratch. And if one of us has to do that then it might as well be you since you need the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Dude you should use a backend programming language for that (PHP o JS with nodeJs) but in your case maybe you could ask a to the user a User and Password and baded on that rou could validate it using an if with Javascript and then redirect to website A or B or Not if user and/or Password are wrong.